# displaying a dialogbox on click of a button in android

Tags: android

how can we display a dialogbox on click of a button in android??

Comment: what type of dialog box can you explain your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create Alert Dilaog in android when your Button is touched, pls see this

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                               displayAlert();
                   retrun false;
}
}

 public  void displayAlert()
    {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hi , I am Alert Dialog")  
           .setTitle("My Alert")  
           .setCancelable(true)  
           .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,  
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                  finish();
              }  
              })  
           .show(); 
    }
```

Comment: I added the code for the click event but whenever i am clicking the button it's showing an error messege..'The application abc(process package_name) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.'

Comment: can you see your Logcat and tell me in which you had this problem

Comment: i am not able to see the logcat..as soon as i am clicking the button it's displaying this error..i even inserted a toggle point to the clickevent but the execution is not stopping ther.

Comment: @Can you post that full code inculding your xml and java code in pastebin, let me help you

Comment: i am working with database..so i think posting just the xml and java code won't do..i hv to post the entire code.. okk is ther any other method by which me can display alerts on button clickevents

Comment: thank you!! the code is fine n it's displaying dialogs properly..i had some errors in my source code..now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in android manifest.Any activity you can create a dialog box using theme.dialog in android manifest.

```
 <activity android:name=".your_activity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

hope this ll help you all guys..